# Prove that it doesn’t exist $n\geq3$ Such that $n$ is divisible by all $m\le n$

Tags: divisibility

**A Claim:**

Let $A$ be a set contains all $n\geq3$ Such that $n$ is divisible by all the numbers less or equal to $n$.
$$A=\{n\geq3 \mid m\mid n, \forall m\le n \}$$

Show that $A=\emptyset$.

This is just another way to explain the question in the title, and why $n\geq3$? It’s because $1,2$ are divisible by all numbers less than themselves.

I don’t have any idea how to prove this claim, i’ve just tried a lot of values and it seems valid, maybe the best way to prove it it’s by contradiction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $A\ne \emptyset$, then exists $n\in A$.

Since every $m\leq n$ divides $n$ then also $n-1\mid n$. But then $$n-1\mid n-(n-1) =1$$ so $n-1 =1$ a contradiction, since $n\geq 3$. Thus $A= \emptyset$.

Comment: I didn’t think about $n-1$, good answer.

Comment: @Yassir How to *discover* the proof: it suffices to find some $m$ coprime to $n$ with $\, 1 < m < n.\,$  Always $1$ is coprime to $n$ but we need something bigger. But coprimes come in "reflection" *pairs* $\,m\leftrightarrow n-m\,$ since $\,\gcd(m,n) = \gcd(n-m,n)\,$ by Euclid. Thus we can use this reflection of $1$, i.e. $\,n-1.\,$ *Arithmetically* this reflection is just *negation* $\!\bmod n,\,$ since $\,n-m\equiv -m\pmod{\!n},\,$ and it is clear that negation of $\,m\,$ doesn't alter its gcd with $\,n.\,$ That's the key idea.

Answer (score 1):

$n-1$ does not divide $n$ for any $n>2$, because $\frac{n}{n-1}$ gives a value between 1 and 2.